# .net Response.redirect in IE between domains returns "Cannot display page"

Tags: internet-explorer, https, response.redirect

On my domain I have a form workflow where users enter data on one form, click continue and enter data on the next form. I am using server.transfer for moving between forms on my domain.

Once users have completed the last form on my domain I use a response.redirect to a third party domain so that the users can complete payment. All pages are in https.

In IE 6 users can move between forms on my domain but cannot be redirected to the third party domain. IE 6 returns an error of "Cannot display page".

I am able to complete the whole process in IE 6 but other users cannot.

Is this due to browser setting or proxy settings and which setting would solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the "users" visit the site you're redirecting to by entering the URL in the address bar? Maybe they don't have access to that site?

Comment: No, they cant see the site if they past the url into IE's address bar.

I'm not sure why they wouldnt have access to the site. Would it be a browser setting?

Comment: It's either a browser setting (proxy?), a DNS problem or a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're debugging blind. Install a traffic monitor (www.fiddler2.com) and see what's coming back on your redirect. If it's a remote user, have them install a capture-only debugger (www.fiddlercap.com) and have them send you the traffic dump.  You'll be able to check what they're seeing.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with the proxy. Fiddler2 helped point me in the right direction. I cant say exactly what the issue was as the network team took my initial findings and solved the solution.